# (REOPENED) Request to reopen "How should I tell my boss that I cannot meet the deadline?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [How should I tell my boss that I cannot meet the deadline?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/82067/3192) was closed as "asking for advice on what to do". However, communicating to the boss that you cannot meet a deadline is a pretty common situation in the workplace, and hence, this is a useful question to have in our repository.

The question already has useful answers, but it would be nonetheless appropriate to keep the question open, so that linking similar questions as duplicate is less confusing. It was closed because it was a semi-rant written out of desperation and focused more on "what to do". I have now trimmed down the description to focus on the main issue. In addition, the "what to do" close reason has been retired now.

Please cast reopen votes if you agree, or post in comments/answer what needs to be further improved or why the question should not be reopened.

Comment: Agreed, vote cast to re-open.